# How does TFVC manage “Get Latest Version” and pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

I’m working on a solution for an application written in C# using Visual Studio 2019, and we use Azure DevOps to store remotely our projects. Now, what happens if I modified a file of this project on my computer (so, there’re pending changes) but I first download the latest version of the files from the remote repository using Visual Studio 2019’s <kbd>Get Latest Version</kbd> option? Is my local version kept even after I download the latest version from the server (so, will pending changes remain untouched)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only modified the file locally and there is no new changes on the remote server, then you click Get Latest Version option, you will get the following prompt:

[image]

If there are changes in both local and remote server, in the case of no conflict, the local pending changes are retained, and the remote changes are merged into the local.

In case of conflict, if you choose `Take Server Version` and overwrite with the remote server version, the local pending changes will not be retained.

[image]